# Need help creating a Python Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help with creating a python class and method. I don't really know what I am doing wrong but I keep getting the correct answer and then this error:
`<__main__.stringToMerge object at 0x7f9161925fd0>`

I want to create an object with two string that merges them alternatively. For example the object would be `obj.s1="aaaaa"`, `obj.s2="bb"` and the correct output would be: `"ababaaa"`.

Ty in advance for any help provided :D

```
class stringToMerge:
  def __init__(self, string1, string2):
    self.string1 = string1
    self.string2 = string2

  def SM(self, string1, string2):
    self.string1 = string1
    self.string2 = string2
    string3 = ""
    i = 0
    while i<len(string1) and i<len(string2):
      string3 = string3+string1[i]
      string3 = string3+string2[i]
      i = i+1
    while i<len(string1):
      string3 = string3+string1[i]
      i = i+1
    while i<len(string2):
      string3 = string3+string1[i]
      i = i+1  
    print(string3)


obj = stringToMerge('aaaaa', 'bb')
obj.SM(obj.string1, obj.string2)
print(obj)
```

Comment: Do you actually *want* a separate `SM` method? And if so, does it actually *need* to take arguments? You're not benefiting from the state stored in the initializer here. Seems like all you really need is a `__init__` and a `__repr__` or `__str__`, no `SM` at all. Are you allowed to use the `itertools` module? If so, the [`roundrobin` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) would do your merging much more cleanly (`''.join(roundrobin(self.string1, self.string2))` does it all).

Comment: You aren't getting an error. That is the generic output when you ask to `print` an object. You should provide a `__repr__` and a `__str__` method in your class. https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Comment: A class with only two methods (one of which is `__init__`) should probably just be a function.

Comment: The call should just be `obj.SM()`; the method doesn't need arguments other than `self`, and you can define `string1 = self.string1; string2 = self.string2` inside the body of the method.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. If you don't want the `main....` to show just remove the last print statement

Comment: `obj` is not the result of `obj.SM(...)`; it's an object that *stores* two strings, which your call to `SM` ignores in favor of taking the strings as arguments. `obj.SM` also neither stores the result nor returns it, rather just printing it to standard output.

Comment: BTW, a note on style - class names should be UpperCamelCase and methods should be snake_case. CAPS should be reserved for constants.

Comment: hey guys, sorry for the dumb question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already your code is printing the expected output. But additionally you are getting this message `<__main__.stringToMerge object at 0x7f9161925fd0>` because you are printing the instance of the class `print(obj)`. Comment or remove this line you won't find this again.

Answer (score 0):

> Your main Issue was that you were not returning anything and you were trying to print the object. Hence the reason it printed out <**main**.stringToMerge object at 0x7f9161925fd0>. In the snippet below I edited the code to be more concise, and I added a return statement to the function. Once this was done, I assigned a variable to the return value of the SM() method and printed said variable

```
class stringToMerge:
  def __init__(self, string1, string2):
    self.string1 = string1
    self.string2 = string2
  def longestString(string1,string2):
      if len(string1) < len(string2):
          return string2
      else:
          return string1
  def SM(self, string1, string2):
    string3 = ""
    i = 0
    for char1,char2 in zip(string1, string2):
        string3 += char1+char2
        i+= 1
    longestString = stringToMerge.longestString(string1,string2)
    return string3+longestString[i:]

obj = stringToMerge('aaaaa', 'bb')
final = obj.SM(obj.string1, obj.string2)
print(final)
```